# How to mock getServerSideProps in jest test

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ts-jest

My component looks like this

```
export const MyComp = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <div>{t("day.1")}</div>;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  let translations = {};
  if (locale !== undefined) {
    translations = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"]);
  }
  return {
    props: {
      ...translations,
    },
  };
};
```

I tried to write the test case but I am not sure how I could mock the getServerSideProps and pass the translations to the component. PLease help.